# Magnetic field shielding for electronics?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, electromagnetic, emf

I am looking at an issue where a PCB design that is powered by a couple of CR2032 batteries will shut off all of a sudden in the presence of strong magnetic fields (around 15-40mT). However, when the batteries are re-seated, the board will start working again, although this is not the most ideal solution. What design considerations do I need to look at to shield the board so that it is unaffected by such strong fields?

Some more information about our setup:

- The board consists of a microcontroller, a couple of light sensors, a solar panel, an LCD screen, and other components (resistors, capacitors, diodes, etc).
- The EMF source is also the light source, which is what is sensed by the sensors on the board.

Comment: Is the magnetic field constant, or varying?  Is the board working, then it stops when it's moved close to the magnetic field source?

Comment: are the cells being moved by the magnetic field to the point of disconnect? ... does it happen if the board is turned over?

Comment: @SteveSh the magnetic field measurements are constant. The board is stationary the whole time the measurements are performed. We have a method of generating EMF, it stops working as soon as the EMF source is turned on.

Comment: @jsotola, the cells do not move at all. The board and its components are stationary the whole time the EMF source is switched on

Comment: What I think is happening is that when you turn on the magnetic field, the time varying field as it builds up induces a voltage in some sensitive traces or components that causes the board to shut down.  Reseating the batteries just causes to board to power up normally, in the presence of the now constant magnetic field.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about what's on the board?

Comment: @SteveSh, I have edited the question - let me know if there is any info missing.

Comment: What do you mean by EMF here? It doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: You might refer to the light circuit as an EMI source - Electromagnetic Interference, (not EMF)

Comment: Most probably layout related. Please show schematic and layout of the board.

Comment: You're certain it's caused by the magnetic field and not by the operation of the board following the sensors senging something (such as the light)? As said elsewhere, reseating probably either resets or glitches the power supply, so unless you're super-sure it's the field (ie can reproduce it with the proximity of a strong, bog-standard magnet-magnet which the board cannot sense by other means) then I'd suspect some kind of droop on the rails caused by a state change in the system.

Comment: What is the frequency of the magnetic field?

Comment: @bobflux - I think he implied that the mag field is constant, once it's turned on.  See his response to my comment earlier in this thread.

Comment: @SteveSh Yeah, but data is more helpful than guesses. What if he measured it with a field meter that displays AC RMS field?... If it is constant, then the problem most likely occurs at turn-on... or it is not as constant as it seems. Like very noisy "DC" from a switching PSU powering a coil...

Comment: How to investigate: turn on the device that emits the field, and then bring in the victim device from another room. Does it stop working when it gets close while the field is already on? This would eliminate turn-on as a culprit. Then, reproduce the bug, pull the battery out and put it back, while the field is still present. Does the problem happen in again? This would also eliminate turn-on. Then, check that magnetic field to see if it is constant, AC, or DC plus noise, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in other comments, moving the battery likely performs a simple reset action (like powering off & back on - the popular modem/router fix). You might prove this to yourself by temporarily using a battery with tack soldered leads.

The interfering field may be putting the microprocessor into a jammed or locked-up condition. Look for high impedance lines (PCB traces or wiring) that do not need to be high impedance, like input lines connected or unconnected, even an open reset line might cause this. You could add pull up or pull down resistors to reduce line impedance. A line with lower impedance will pick up less non-contact magnetic or electrical noise. Reduce or eliminate lines that are excessively long or create loop patterns. A long PCB trace can act like an antenna, a loop or circular trace can act like a half turn inductor picking up magnetic noise.

For the microprocessor, you might consider including watch-dog timer code within your software (or use a microprocessor that includes this function in hardware). A watch-dog timer can often provide an escape from a jammed or locked-up condition. You might even count the number of watch-dog timer events to warn an operator of adverse operating conditions.

As for physical shielding, you could insure that your PCB uses large ground planes under sensitive circuits. Installing the PCB in a metal enclosure is almost always a good start to minimize external interference. You could also try a sheet of Mu-Metal above or below (or even around the PCB). Ferrite beads placed on sensitive I/O wiring can help reduce the pickup of high frequency interference too.

Comment: Physical shielding, with a piece of steel (easier to come by than Mu- metal) placed between the source of the mag field and the pcb is an easy experiment to run.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plot of magnetic attenuation by metallic shields versus thickness and frequency in Ott H. W., "Noise Reduction Techniques In Electronic Systems, second edition", Figure 6-22, page 185. He says that "testing was done using shields from 0.076 mm (0.003") to 1.52 mm (0.060") thick", and the source and receiver were 2.54 mm (0.1") apart. Here are the highlights.

- At 1 kHz, Mu metal is the best for shielding, followed by steel, copper, and aluminum. Mu is about 35 % better than the same thickness of steel.
- Copper and aluminum do little to shield 1 kHz magnetic noise.
- At 10 kHz and 100 kHz, steel is the best of the four materials.
- 1.52 mm (0.060") thick steel only provides about 20 dB of attenuation at 1 kHz.
- The attenuation in dB is roughly linear with respect to thickness.

Magnetic fields are also picked up by loops in the circuit. If possible reorient the circuit 90 degrees from the source, and if there are any wires going to the batteries, twist them together.